# Why is the slider's minimumValueImage in iOS gets blurred?

Tags: ios, uislider

I am using 24x24 point png images for this slider's minimumValueImage and maximumValueImage, But when I run them on iPhone simulator it appears but blurred/stretched. Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: For the iPhone you would need a double resolution image.

Comment: Hi @matt do you mean I will need 48x48 point image

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be specified as the 2x version of the image.

Comment: Ideally use an asset catalogue and provide either a PDF resource or a set of 1x, 2x and 3x variations. The area your icon is occupying on screen is a lot bigger than 24x24px so iOS is scaling your image up, using generic means.

Comment: Also for iPhone 6s you need a triple resolution version. This is all true for every image, ever.

Comment: @matt you mean the iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 6S plus and iPhone 7 plus. The iPhone 6s use the `@2x`

Comment: Hi @Tommy is there any step by step documentation on this asset catalogue setup?

Comment: @rckoenes you're right of course

Comment: @keyur I think Matt, below, has beaten me to answering that. I endorse his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possible screen resolutions, so every image in your app needs to come in three versions. Here's how:

1. Make three images in three sizes: in your case, that would be 24x24, 48x48, 72x72.
2. Edit the asset catalog. Create an image set. Give the image set a name.
3. Select the image set. You will see the Universal display with three slots for images:

   [image]
4. Drag the small image into the 1x slot, the medium image into the 2x slot, and the big image into the 3x slot.
5. In your code, refer to the image by the name of the image set.

Follow those instructions for *every image in your app*.